# Display Custom IRandomAccessStream in UWP

Tags: uwp, video-streaming, mediaelement

I am writing a Video Calling app in UWP and C#. 
For now I am recording video and sending it to a server.
I have a custom [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream) that has the following `ReadAsync()` method:

```
  public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer buffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
    {

        return AsyncInfo.Run<IBuffer, uint>(async (cancellationToken, progress) =>
        {                
            IBuffer newBuffer = await socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, count, options).AsTask(cancellationToken, progress);
            position += newBuffer.Length;
            return newBuffer;

        });
    }
```

When Initializing the MainPage, I use the following method to set the [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream) source:

```
mediaPlayer.SetSource(receiver, "video/mp4");
```

But when I run the app, nothing is displayed, while the `ReadAsync()` and `Seek()` methods of the stream are being called and no Exceptions are thrown.

What am I doing wrong? And is it even possible to display a custom [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream)? And if so, does someone have a working example?

I am recording video like this:
`_mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto), currentOutputStream);`

Comment: I found the following sample on Git Hub that you might find helpful https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication. It captures the video on a device and sends it to another device in real time

Comment: That example uses an URL, while I am using a StreamSocket to send data...